# Python unable to scrape javascript

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to scrape the time and the scores from this website:  https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/in-play/all

When I inspect the element, it shows:

```html
<span class="btmarket__livescore-item team-a">2</span>
```

2 is the value I'm after.  When I look at the web request I am seeing:

```html
<span class="btmarket__livescore-item team-a"> </span>
```

(missing the '2').

I've tried using render from HTMLSession and also webdriver but no luck.

Thx!

As per requested.  Can reproduce manuall if you use Chrome 'inspect' and also viewing page source.

```js
import requests
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.get('https://sports.williamhill.com/betting/en-gb/in-play/football',headers=headers)
print (r.text)  #search for 'team-a'
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Sites with dynamic content can be loaded with [`Selenium`](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/)